# Is polynomial division via the grid/box method foolproof?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

According to my friend, it doesn't work in some cases and you are forced to use the long division technique.

Example of grid method: https://www.tes.com/teaching-resource/polynomial-division-6394436

Note: My level of maths right now is at an A level standard (17-18 year old)

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule ?

Comment: @Ihf I don't think so, I'm not sure if it's given a formal name... I only know it as the 'grid method' for dividing polynomials (see the link in original question for an example, hopefully it should be clear).  [NB:  Transferred here from "answer" box, as OP has lost access to the unregistered account posting the Q.]